# getStaticProps not called on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I have an app that routes to a path based on id. Here is the route information in `App.js`:

```
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="yawara-advanced" element={<AdvancedYawara />} />
          <Route path=":id" element={<Detail />}/>
          <Route path="*" element={<p>Not found!</p>} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the content of `[id].js`

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  console.log("getStaticProps!")
  const SSR = withSSRContext(context);
  const yawara = SSR.DataStore.query(YawaraModel, context.params.id );

  return {
    props: { recipe: serializeModel(yawara) },
  }
}

export default function Detail({yawara}) {
  console.log("Detail!")
  return <TechniqueListCard yawaraModel={yawara}/>;
}
```

The route works correctly. A page is opened based on the ID passed.  The function `Detail` is also invoked. There is a log entry verifying it. But, `getStaticProps` never gets called. It was my understanding that it would be called when the page loads. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that NextJS wasn't really installed. Therefore the async functions were simply ignored.